# Is PFIFO an engine in nouveau kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, nouveau

I recently received the following error in my syslog:

```
syslog:Apr 28 09:59:02 vostrodell kernel: [  883.401212] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0039824400 on channel 12 [3ed04000 systemd-logind[576]] engine 05 [PFIFO] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [SEMAPHORE] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
```

So I went to the documentation:

- https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/KernelModuleParameters.html#debug

and I tried adding the following file:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau.conf 
# debug nouveau
options nouveau debug="PFIFO=debug"
```

However this is not being passed as expected:

```
# cat /sys/module/nouveau/parameters/debug 
(null)
```

I understand that `PFIFO` is not listed under `debug` section on the documentation page, but should fall under the category of `any engine (see above)`:

- https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/KernelModuleParameters.html#config

I believe this is the correct *engine* to pass as kernel module parameter.

Did I misread the documentation ? What should be the correct way to track to gather some meaning full information about this bug (in case I reproduce it) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue was that `nouveau` is starting from `initramfs`.

To change load options for this kind of modules one need to run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

to get the setting applied, otherwise no change are seen.